# Migrating taxonomy terms only if the destination doesn't have the term name

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, migrations

Is it possible to migrate taxonomy terms by checking if the source term name matches with the destination term name.

I would like to skip the migration if the term is present in destination.
Tried with entity_lookup plugin, but its generating new terms. 
Here is the current approach which is not working for me-

```
process:
  name:
   -
     plugin: entity_lookup
     source: uuid
     value_key: uuid
     bundle_key: vid
     bundle: my_bundle
     entity_type: taxonomy_term
  description: description
  vid:
    -
      plugin: log
```

An example would be great.
Thanks.